# How to calculate the starting and end date difference using awk

Tags: awk

I need to print the difference (in days) in ($6) between the starting and end date of records for each unique ID ($5) on a new field.
the data looks like this

```
7  65  2    5   32070  2010-12-14    13:25:30    
7  82  2    10  41920  2010-12-14    11:30:45  
7  83  1    67  29446  2010-12-14    04:15:25      
7  81  1    47  32070  2011-5-11     08:14:20  
7  83  1    67  29446  2011-6-22     07:13:24
7  82  2    10  41920  2011-5-14     06:15:25
```

I need to see as follows:

```
7  65  2    5   32070  2010-12-14    13:25:30   147  
7  82  2    10  41920  2010-12-14    11:30:45   150  
7  83  1    67  29446  2010-12-14    04:15:25   189  
7  81  1    47  32070  2011-5-11     08:14:20   147  
7  83  1    67  29446  2011-6-22     07:13:24   189  
7  82  2    10  41920  2011-5-14     06:15:25   150
```

I have used the following code but give me error message. could you help me if you have another option?

```
awk '{  
       split($6,arr,"-")  
      a=sprintf("%s %s %s 0 0 0",arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])  
      d=mktime(a)    
      delta[$5]=delta[$5] " " d  
     }   
   END {for(i in delta) {print i, delta[i]}  }'  filename > tmp.dat  

awk '{  
     if (FILENAME=="tmp.dat" )  
     {   
       delta[$1]=$0;   
       next  
     }  
     if (FILENAME=="filename")  
     {   
       a="-1"  
       if($5 in delta)  
      {  
        cnt=split(delta[$5],arr)  
       if(cnt==3)  
       {  
         a=arr[3] - arr[2]  
         a/=86400  
         a=int(a)  
       }  
       }  
      print $0, a        
      next  
       }  
        }' tmp.dat filename
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247157/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-records-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-a) is related.

Comment: Seems like the same question was asked elsewhere: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333235/how-can-i-get-the-difference-in-days-using-awk/333243#333243

Answer (score 2):

In awk. Source file is read in twice. On the first go time difference is computed, on the second records are outputed with appended time differencies.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {
           c = "date -d \""$6 "\" +%s";   # use system date for epoch time seconds
           c | getline d;                 # execute command in c var, output to d 
           a[$5] = (($5 in a) ? d-a[$5] : d); # set or subtract from array
           next                           # skip to next record
       } {                                # for the second go:
           # $1=$1;                       # uncomment to clean trailing space
           print $0, int(a[$5]/86400)     # print record and time  difference
       }' file file
7  65  2    5   32070  2010-12-14    13:25:30     147
7  82  2    10  41920  2010-12-14    11:30:45   150
7  83  1    67  29446  2010-12-14    04:15:25       189
7  81  1    47  32070  2011-5-11     08:14:20   147
7  83  1    67  29446  2011-6-22     07:13:24 189
7  82  2    10  41920  2011-5-14     06:15:25   150
```

The spacing before time difference varies because your data has trailing space after `$NF`. You can trim it out with for example `$1=$1;` before the `print`.

**EDIT**: It expects that there are only 2 of each *unique IDs* in field `$5`. When the first occurrance of an ID is found, the date in field `$6` (and only the date part) is converted to seconds and stored to array `a[$5]`. When the next one is found, the time stored to `a[$5]` is subtracted from the later found time and stored to `a[$5]`. If there are more than 2 occurrences of the *unique ID `$5`* time in `a[$5]` is subtracted from the last found time and resulting in chaos.

Comment: well done. I didn't think this was trival. If the OP had a better file format I would of choose to use Python to solve this issue

Comment: @James Brown When i tried the command for the given sample data i got an out put different from yours. In addition, Does the command take in to account the other days in between the starting and end date of the records? my data set have many date records in between starting and end dates for each unique ID. Here is the problem I got when i print the command

Comment: its not exactly what you found

Comment: @James Brown I have more than twice occurance of an ID.

Comment: Well, that's something that should go to the requirements and into the data example and especially the rule of how to handle the multiple dates is needed.

Comment: @Jemes Brown could you help me in this regards?

Comment: How should the dates be handled if there are more than 2 of each id? Add the rules to the original question and edit the test data and expected output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for an awk solution but maybe consider a Python/Pandas solution for this.

Convert source file

```
awk '{ $1 = $1; $0 = $0; print }' OFS=, tmp.dat > tmp1.dat
```

Then use pandas

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                            
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                   


df=pd.read_csv("/tmp/tmp1.dat",names=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],dtype={1:str,
                                                            2:str,
                                                            3:str,
                                                            4:str,
                                                            5:str,
                                                            6:str})                                                                                                                                          
df[5]=pd.to_datetime((df[5].astype(str)+" "+df[6].astype(str))); del df[6] 

for i,j in df.groupby(4):
    df.ix[df[4]==i,'days']=j[5].diff().fillna(method='bfill')

df['days']=(df['days']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')).astype(int)

df.to_csv("/tmp/ans)
```

ans looks like this

```
7,65,2,5,32070,2010-12-14 13:25:30,147
7,82,2,10,41920,2010-12-14 11:30:45,150
7,83,1,67,29446,2010-12-14 04:15:25,190
7,81,1,47,32070,2011-05-11 08:14:20,147
7,83,1,67,29446,2011-06-22 07:13:24,190
7,82,2,10,41920,2011-05-14 06:15:25,150
```