# How can i get the difference between two starting dates using awk?

Tags: awk

I need to print the difference (in days) between the oldest date of $4 and $2 for each unique Id ($1).

here is the data

```
32070  2010-12-14    13:25:30  20101211 13:25:30  
41920  2010-12-14    11:30:45  20101213 11:30:45
29446  2010-12-14    04:15:25  20101211 04:15:25   
32070  2011-05-11    08:14:20  20101211 08:12:23
29446  2011-6-22     07:13:24  20101211 10:13:50
41920  2011-5-14     06:15:25  20101213 12:14:05
32070  2011-5-13     12:11:05  20101211 06:12:30
41920  2011-5-16     05:15:08  20101213 15:13:30
29446  2011-6-23     10:20:15  20101211 10:12:16
```

out put will look like this

```
32070  2010-12-14    13:25:30  20101211 03:25:30 3 
41920  2010-12-14    11:30:45  20101213 08:30:15 1
29446  2010-12-14    04:15:25  20101211 09:15:25 3  
32070  2011-05-11    08:14:20  20101211 04:12:23 3
29446  2011-6-22     07:13:24  20101211 10:13:50 3
41920  2011-5-14     06:15:25  20101213 12:14:05 1
32070  2011-5-13     12:11:05  20101211 06:12:30 3
41920  2011-5-16     05:15:08  20101213 15:13:30 1
29446  2011-6-23     10:20:15  20101211 10:12:16 3
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: _I wrote the following code_ you say [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333235/how-can-i-get-the-difference-in-days-using-awk/) and use my code copied from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41344338/4162356). Pretty uncool.

Comment: @JamesBrown I know but the question is different.

Comment: @Alula you missed the point - it's rude (at best) to claim you wrote code that someone else wrote for you. You've asked and received answers for about 20 questions so far - if you haven't learned enough yet to start attempting to solve problems yourself then this approach isn't working for you and you should take the time to read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins so you can start learning a little about awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alula- I think there is a mistake in your output from 4th line eg-> how come difference of 2011-05-11(5th month of 2011) and 20101211(12th month of 2010) difference could be 3 days?
If this is a typo, could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '{gsub(/-/," ",$2);;printf("%s %d\n",$0,(mktime($2 FS 0 FS 0 FS 0)-mktime(substr($4,1,4) FS substr($4,5,2) FS substr($4,7,2) FS 0 FS 0 FS 0))/(3600 * 24))}'  Input_file
```

Let me know if this helps you.

**EDIT:** Adding answer as per OP's request now too.

```
awk '!A[$2,$4]++{E=$2;R=$4;gsub(/-/," ",E);;printf("%s %d\n",$0,(mktime(E FS 0 FS 0 FS 0)-mktime(substr(R,1,4) FS substr(R,5,2) FS substr(R,7,2) FS 0 FS 0 FS 0))/(3600 * 24))}'  Input_file
```

@Alula: Kindly do let me know if this helps you.

Comment: My interest is to print the difference between the very first (oldest) record of $2 from $4. sorry for lack of clarification.

Comment: @Alula: You should look once at James Brown's comment and check the link provided by him. Also I have edited my answer too, kindly let me know if that helps too.